# How to transfer redux toolkit store via vite plugin federation

Tags: reactjs, vite, redux-toolkit

host vite.config.js

```
import federation from '@originjs/vite-plugin-federation'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        federation({
            name: 'app',
            remotes: {
                remoteApp: 'http://localhost:5001/assets/remoteEntry.js',
                store: 'http://localhost:5002/assets/remoteEntry.js',
            },
            shared: ['react', 'react-dom'],
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        modulePreload: false,
        target: 'esnext',
        minify: false,
        cssCodeSplit: false,
    },
})
```

remote vite.config.js

```
import federation from '@originjs/vite-plugin-federation'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        federation({
            name: 'remote_app',
            filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
            remotes: {
                store: 'http://localhost:5002/assets/remoteEntry.js',
            },
            exposes: {
                './Button': './src/Button',
            },
            shared: ['react', 'react-dom'],
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        modulePreload: false,
        target: 'esnext',
        minify: false,
        cssCodeSplit: false,
    },
})
```

store vite.config.js

```
import federation from '@originjs/vite-plugin-federation'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        federation({
            name: 'store',
            filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
            exposes: {
                './store': './src/store',
            },
            shared: ['react', 'react-dom'],
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        modulePreload: false,
        target: 'esnext',
        minify: false,
        cssCodeSplit: false,
    },
})
```

store/src/store

```
import { configureStore, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'counter',
    initialState: {
        count: 0,
    },
    reducers: {
        increment: state => {
            state.count += 1
        },
        clear: state => {
            state.count = 0
        },
    },
})

const { increment, clear } = counterSlice.actions

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        counter: counterSlice.reducer,
    },
})

export function useStore() {
    const count = useSelector(state => state.counter.count)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    return {
        count,
        increment: () => dispatch(increment()),
        clear: () => dispatch(clear()),
    }
}

// eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
export function StoreProvider({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
}
```

remote/src/main.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { StoreProvider } from 'store/store'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <StoreProvider>
            <App />
        </StoreProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
)
```

remote/src/Button.jsx

```
import { useStore } from 'store/store'
export const Button = () => {
    const { count, increment } = useStore()
    return (
        <div>
            <button className='shared-btn' onClick={increment}>
                Click me: {count}
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Button
```

This code causes an error in remote

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'store' of 'useReduxContext$1(...)' as it is null.
    at useSelector (__federation_expose_Store-6073bd77.js:1385:7)
    at useStore (__federation_expose_Store-6073bd77.js:1786:17)
    at Button (__federation_expose_Button-064de5a1.js:103:32)
    at Xh (__federation_shared_react-dom.js:202:137)
    at Wk (__federation_shared_react-dom.js:325:339)
    at Vk (__federation_shared_react-dom.js:315:393)
    at Uk (__federation_shared_react-dom.js:315:322)
    at Jk (__federation_shared_react-dom.js:315:181)
    at Ok (__federation_shared_react-dom.js:306:88)
    at Hk (__federation_shared_react-dom.js:303:432)
```

Is it possible to transfer redux store via vite plugin federation, if yes where is the mistake here, and if not, what is the best state manager to choose? Or maybe there are other ways to transfer stores between microfrontends.

Comment: Also, don't bury the lead. We shouldn't need to scroll through a wall of code snippets to get to what you are asking for help with. It seems you are asking several questions and also requesting recommendations. Please try to narrow the focus of the post to a specific on-topic issue/question. Take a look a [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) for other tips to improve the quality of your post.